# Writing images to hard disk fast using openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use a picamera and a raspberryPi to record image sequences using libcamera2 and openCV at around 2-3 Hz frame rate. The camera delivers   4056 x 3040 x 3 uint8 arrays. Writing the data as images or video to the hard disk is limiting my recording frame rate significantly.

When I try to append images to a video file using `cv2.VideoWriter()` converting the single images to the video format adds around a second to each single frame. When I try to dump the single images as bmp files (no compression) using `imwrite()` to the hard disk my frame rate is not stable, most frames take 0.5 seconds while every 10th frame takes 2-4 seconds. Superficially, it seems that there no background processes that cause these delays.

What is the best general approach to write individual frames as fast as possible to the harddisk? Is there a compressionless and fast format for the VideoWriter?

Comment: Better harddrive? One frame is 37 Meg, 3 frames about 110 Meg, and a spinning 5400 RPM harddrive is likely topping at 120 Meg. Add in necessary overhead an .5 seconds per frame is pretty good. The 2-4 second delays could be when pipeline buffers are full or the disk starts moving the head. If you are using a 5400 hdd, move to an ssd (or at least a 7200 hdd and look for a vendor with good performance numbers). Also, dedicating the hdd to writes (keep os / etc on another drive) can help reduce head movement.

Comment: How long do you need to sustain these rates? Have you tried saving as JPEG? Why compressionless? Or do you mean lossless?

Comment: The unstable bmp writing is likely either a linux file system.thing or a linux buffer/caching thing where writing operations don't block but first write to a buffer which then is emptied in the background. But once the buffer is full, the next operation will block. First you should check whether your system has enough writing speed to write the whole raw data in-time (including some overhead). If that is the case you should add your own internal buffer (and writing from a separate thread)  to overcome random system latencies.

Comment: If yout drive is even theoretically not fast enough you could try to get hardware accelerated jpeg encoding or h264 encoding running to trade space for processing. Or, if you have color images, tey to access and save the raw images instead of demosaiced (debayered) images. If you have mono images make sure they are not saved as 3 channel (which would triple the needed space and writing time). Mono images can be saved as .pgm for example.

Comment: Are the reads and writes running in parallel in multiple threads or processes? That would be the first thing to explore, if it's not the case already. I'd also consider dumping raw data into a preallocated memory mapped file. Since the raw frames will have fixed size, that should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Switch to an SSD.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have this running in a loop and the disk write is causing the lag issue.  It is not your program, but probably the operating system have to grab, allocate, and check for new disk space that is causing occasional lag spikes.  It is not that much data, so it is a bit surprising.

You can place the writing in it's own thread with a queue.  As long as the writing can keep up with the FPS you want to output, you can grab frames on a consistent schedule and let the writer deal with the lag.

In the code below you will need to modify how the data is written out to suite your needs. I.e. replace the `with open...` with however you want to write the data.

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from queue import Queue

class ThreadWriter(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.event = Event()

    def write_file(self, path: str, data: bytes):
        self.queue.put((path, data))
        return self.queue.qsize()

    def close(self, wait=True):
        if wait:
            while not self.queue.empty():
                continue
        self.event.set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.is_set():
            if self.queue.empty():
                continue
            path, data = self.queue.get()
            with open(path, 'wb') as fp:
                fp.write(data)
```

In your main program, create a `ThreadWriter` object, start it, and then push the data to the thread in your loop.

```
# [imports]

FPS = 2.5
writer = ThreadWriter()
writer.start()

while True:
    # you code here to pull frames
    # n is the count of pulled data
    file_name = f'image-{n:0>4}.jpg'
    img_bytes = convert_to_jpeg(img)  # fake function for example.
    writer.write_file(file_name, img_bytes)

    sleep(1/FPS)

writer.close()
```